# liquibase: how to call and execute databse function via liquibase?

Tags: database, liquibase

databse:postgreSql

I have a requirement to call a database function via liquibase.

is there a way to execute a postgres function via databaseChangeLog in liquibase ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `<sql>` (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) section in changelog to call database function

Answer (score 0):

I was able to put `SELECT myfunc();` in a "liquibase formatted sql" changeset and it appeared to have worked. Here is the portion of the changeset code:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset usrname:20181105-1
--preconditions onFail:CONTINUE onError:HALT
ALTER TABLE lbo.lbo_layers ADD COLUMN ole_mod_cd TEXT CHECK (ole_mod_cd IN (NULL,'HPMS','LBE'));
SELECT lba.utl_update_gdo();
```